# first function uses a variable from the second function, but second function also invokes first function

Tags: javascript, function, invoke

I have this piece of JavaScript code, and I want it to be able to use `calculate()` in the second function (which does work), but the problem is that the first function uses a variable declared in the second function. Also, I need `var first=prompt` to be executed only when `chemicalcalc` is invoked.

```
function calculate(){
  var calctrans=parseInt(firsttrans, 10)
  return calctrans;
}

function chemicalcalc(){
  var first=prompt("Enter first term\nLeave bank to go back to element finder");
  if(first==""){
    calculate();
  }else{
    var firsttrans=first.replace("h", 1);
  }
}

chemicalcalc();
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass firsttrans to calculate() in the first place?  You say that you want to call calculate() if first is an empty string, but the whole point of declaring a separate firsttrans variable, according to your current code, is to replace all h's with 1's in first, so wouldn't it make sense to call calculate() after you've already done this, or maybe break out of the function/do something else if first is an empty string?

Comment: Even if you could access `firsttrans`, it would not be defined, because you have not given it a value when calling `calculate`. It is only given a value in the `else` part, where you don't call `calculate`. Also, you are not doing anything with the value that `calculate` returns... So, maybe you can explain what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

By nesting the `calculate()` inside of `chemicalcalc`, you allow `calculate` to have access to the parent function's scope.

**However, if the user doesn't enter anything and just hits ENTER at the prompt, your code will invoke `calculate`, which will then attempt to use `firsttrans`, which won't have a value because the branch of the `if` that sets the value isn't entered, so you have a logic error there.**

I have removed that `if/then` logic to show how the rest of the function would work.

```js
function chemicalcalc(){
  var first = prompt("Enter first term\nLeave bank to go back to element finder");
  
  var firsttrans = first.replace("h", 1);
  
  // Invoke calculate and return whatever it returns
  return calculate();
  
  // Nested functions always have access to the parent's scope
  function calculate(){
    var calctrans = parseInt(firsttrans, 10)
    return calctrans;
  }
}

console.log(chemicalcalc());
```

Another option (instead of nesting functions) is to simply pass the second function the data it requires as an argument:

```js
function chemicalcalc(){
  var first = prompt("Enter first term\nLeave bank to go back to element finder");
  
  var firsttrans = first.replace("h", 1);
  
  // Invoke calculate and pass it the data it needs, then return whatever it returns
  return calculate(firsttrans);
}

// Now the function expects data to be passed by the caller
function calculate(data){
  var calctrans = parseInt(data, 10)
  return calctrans;
}

console.log(chemicalcalc());
```

Comment: that seems to make sense, but when i tried it out, after inputting "h", nothing happened? could it be because calculate() was invoked out of the scope where it was defined?

Comment: @KrazyKoder22 I'm not sure what you mean. When I run this and enter, say "h23", I get "123" outputted.

Comment: ok, it's working now. also sometimes when i nest a function inside another function, my ide tells me to move the nested function to the function body root. why doesn't it say that for this code?

Comment: @KrazyKoder22 Nesting functions is completely normal and often desirable in JavaScript. The IDE will tell you to "un" nest your functions when it determines that the nested function does not rely on the scope of the parent. That's not the case here, the nested function does rely on the scope of the parent, so nesting is warranted. That's why it's not complaining.